# Error de syntaxis en PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-plugin

Estoy tratando de instalar un plugin en Wordpress sin embargo recibo el siguiente error:

```
    Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting '|' or variable (T_VARIABLE) in /home/domain.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/smsifywoo/Smsifywoo/includes/SMSNotification.php on line 181
```

Y la línea 181 tiene lo siguiente:

```
    } catch ( Exception ) {

        // log error and set datetime for SMS to 'N/A'
        // wc_twilio_sms()->log( $e->getMessage() );
        $formatted_datetime = esc_html__( 'N/A', 'smsifywoo' );
    }
```

Intente poner el catch ( Exception $e ) {

Pero no funciona.

Mi PHP es 7.4
No puedo actualizar el PHP por decisión del dueño de la web

Comment: `: bool|int ` fija que el type de lo que retorna la función puede ser `bool` o `int` esto no está soportado en versiones anteriores a la [`8.0`](https://php.watch/versions/8.0/union-types) podes borrar `: bool|int ` y el código seguramente te diga que la versión no está soportada. para ver cual es la versión mínima fijate si encontras en el mismo archivo un define con `MIN_PHP_VERSION`; btw es común al desarrollar con php 8.x local y al subir al host descubris q aún están en la 7.x

Comment: @aloMalbarez Si acabo de actualizar en la pregunta las líneas pero pide como mínimo PHP 7.0

Comment: A lo que se refiere @aloMalbarez es que este tipo de declaración  `unTipo|otroTipo`, que se llama *Union Types*, empezó a usarse sólo a partir de la versión 8 de PHP. Entonces, si ese código no corre en la versión 8 o superior será erróneo. Lo que debes verificar es la versión de PHP que hay actualmente en tu servidor.

Comment: en ese caso borrale el `|int` , al usar un "comparison" con `version_compare` [el return value sería true o false](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.version-compare.php), puede q se les pasó ese detalle ( o directamente actualizar php al 8.x )

Comment: Puedes verlo con una versión simplificada del código ejecutada en PHP 8 y en PHP 7. [En la versión 8 funciona](https://3v4l.org/lgr6t#v8.2.11) sin embargo, [en la versión 7 no funciona](https://3v4l.org/lgr6t#v7.3.7).

Comment: @A.Cedano Entiendo, si justo estaba leyendo el documento que compartío aloMalbarez y en efecto, mi server actualmente por compatibilidad con otras secciones del sitio y el código esta en 7.4 y es imposible pasarlo a 8.0 ya que el cliente decidió que así se quede. Entonces no se como podría hacerle para hacerlo retro-compatible.

Comment: editar el code y desactivar el auto update para ese plugin es lo usual. dejar una nota en el `functions.php` del child theme asi futuro-yo no anda persiguiendo fantasmas al hacer un upgrade. podes notificar al autor del plugin acerca de ese tema tb

Comment: @aloMalbarez Muchas gracias, en efecto al borrar el |int se soluciono ese error, el problema es que hay más lineas como esas incluso una con esta estructura: private WC_Order_Refund|WC_Order|bool $order; y me da el  error de que espera T_VARIABLE. Entonces creo definitivamente el plugin no esta pensado para versiones anteriores al 8.0. Gracias de cualquier forma.

Comment: Si quieres escribir un código que sea compatible con múltiples versiones, una forma limpia de hacerlo es como se explica en [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28788010/5587982). Lo interesante de ese enfoque es que en un solo archivo puedes agrupar formas de declaración por versiones. Si se trata de funcionas propias del lenguaje, puedes hacer una verificación con [`function_exists()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php), para declarar tu función personalizada solamente cuando no exista.

Comment: si es plugin de pago podes pedir un refund o una versión compatible; si el min php version es realmente 7.0 pasales este doc https://developer.wordpress.org/coding-standards/wordpress-coding-standards/php/#type-declarations

Comment: Y en las versiones anteriores del Plugin??? Puedes bajar una del 7?? En el soporte del plugin te pueden ayudar y si no es mucho, refactorizalo tu...

Comment: @Yenn Ya lo estuve modificando, pero llegue a una parte que ya no supe como hacerlo, esta al final de la pregunta. El plugin es nuevo y el desarrollador no contesta por eso acudi con ustedes.

Comment: ¿Y si consideras actualizar tu PHP al menos a 8.x? PHP 7 ya está [sin soporte](https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php). Incluso hasta php 8.0 está en estado de soporte extendido solo hasta diciembre 2023.

Comment: El cliente no quiere que se actualice porque hay otros plugins que desarrollaron y no funcionan y no quieren pagar para que se actualicen...

Comment: Pero dice error de sintaxis, una lastima que no se tenga más código. Y acá creo que no ayudan a plugin porque estos están creados por una empresa :-(

Comment: @Yenn a mi me toco leer todo el código e irlo adaptando a PHP 7.4 no hubo de otra.